# Swift iOS -CollectionView how to scroll cells off of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView with 4 cells. Since there are only 4 cell inside the collection view it won't scroll any further.

When scrolling up I want to scroll the 4 cells off of the screen (collectionView will appear empty). Once the cells are off screen I want the scrolling to stop, I don't want to scroll forever. When scrolling back down I want to scroll the 4 cells back onto the scene.

I tried changing the `collectionView.bounds.origin` and the `collectionView.contentSize.height` but neither worked, I still couldn't scroll the 4 cells off of the screen.

I can always add clear cells but that seems like a hack.

**What is the appropriate way to accomplish this?**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
       layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
       layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

       collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
       collectionView.delegate = self
       collectionView.dataSource = self
       collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
       collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
       collectionView.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: myCell)
       view.addSubview(collectionView)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: myCell, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
       cell.textLabel.text = "Hello"
       return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 44)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the scrollView's `contentInset`:

```
collectionView?.contentInset.bottom = collectionView?.frame.height ?? 0
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I'll try it in about 15 min and get back to you

Comment: where should I set that line of code at -in scrollViewDidScroll?

Comment: Try it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: it works but there's 1 problem. It scrolls forever. I wanted it to stop once the 4 cells are off the screen. I'm going to upvote the answer because it does answer the question. I'm to adjust the question to reflect what I didn't anticipate.

Comment: I just tried it there, it didn't work. It won't scroll at all once I set it in viewDidLoad

Comment: actually it did work. I had the scroll view indicator hidden so it looked like it was scrolling forever. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Perfect. Glad I could help!